# Why are points from a MySQL WMS layer, displayed on a OpenLayers 2 map, reading out a lat/long location that is off by 500 meters,

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, mysql

I have a MySQL table containing MySQL point geometries (MySQL 5.7). I have configured a GeoServer WMS layer using this data. I cannot set the native srs (not enabled in config dialog), declared srs is set to EPSG:4326 and srs handling is set to force declared. The layer displays well but when zooming close and hovering the mouse over point, in the OpenLayers lat/long readout is typically around 300-500 meters off. Seems worse in the x (longitude) axis. I verified that the stored point have 5 decimal places. Verified by selecting point from table and displaying at text  with `AsWKT` function.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Can you add the relevant parts of your code? the most likely problem is that your map is actually in a Web Mercator projection or that your data is not in epsg:4326